# How to deploy staging env using a docker container on Heroku

Tags: heroku, docker-compose

I use to deploy docker-compose on heroku.

like this command↓

1. heroku container:login
2. heroku container:push web
3. heroku container:release web
4. heroku open

And, I am trying to add a staging environment. What commands can I use to deploy to the staging environment?

I would like to deploy a docker container to the staging environment in the same way as the prod environment.

Thank you.